# Calling javascript function to make an AJAX call from form not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking around on here, I discovered that the optimal way to call a Javascript function from HTML was to place the function itself in HTML, rather than an external Javascript file. So I kept looking around online and found some short tutorials that I was able to modify to suit my needs. In the end, I had the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test Webpage</title>
    </head>

    <script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
        function createCard(input_form) {
            alert("Card is being created!");
            $.ajax({
                url: "create_card.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {input_form.deck.value, input_form.card_name.value, input_form.front_text.value, input_form.front_media.value, input_form.back_text.value, input_form.back_media.value}
            )};
    } </script>

    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Create a card</h2>
            <form id="create_card_form" action="" method="GET"><!--action="create_card.php" method="post">-->
                Deck: <input type="text" name="deck"><br><br>
                Card Name: <input type="text" name="card_name"><br><br>
                Front Text: <input type="text" name="front_text"><br><br>
                Front Media (X: Image, Y: Video) <input type="text" name="front_media"><br><br>
                Back Text: <input type="text" name="back_text"><br><br>
                Back Media (X: Image, Y: Video) <input type="text" name="back_media"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="CREATE CARD" onClick="createCard(this.form)">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, the function is not getting called. I know this because the alert never occurs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @DaveNewton: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` it looks like it has to do with referencing the form elements but I don't see an unexpected `.`

Comment: What's `data: {input_form.deck.value, input_form.card_name.value, input_form.front_text.value, input_form.front_media.value, input_form.back_text.value, input_form.back_media.value}`

Comment: @j08691 I found the code in a tutorial as a way to reference the elements of a form in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the action from form or use the script from there.

Your parenthesis / curly brackets are wrong for sure

```
$.ajax({ )};
```

Comment: This is part of the issue, but the main issue seems to be the usage of object notation to represent an array.

Comment: @DavidT The first issue is that his JavaScript syntax is incorrect, so the `createCard` function doesn't get created. That is why the alert is not seen.

Comment: @JackA. the correction specified in this answer does is not a complete fix and the alert will still not show.

Answer (score 0):

You're treating a javascript object as an array.

You're passing in
`{input_form.deck.value, input_form.card_name.value, input_form.front_text.value, input_form.front_media.value, input_form.back_text.value, input_form.back_media.value}`

instead of `[input_form.deck.value, input_form.card_name.value, input_form.front_text.value, input_form.front_media.value, input_form.back_text.value, input_form.back_media.value]`

Arrays are represented as `[]` not `{}` in JavaScript

The recommended way to handle this would be to serialize your form:

```
   function createCard(input_form) {
       alert("Card is being created!");
        $.ajax({
            url: "create_card.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(input_form).serialize()
        });
    }
```

Full working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Webpage</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Create a card</h2>
            <form id="create_card_form" action="" method="GET"><!--action="create_card.php" method="post">-->
                Deck: <input type="text" name="deck"><br><br>
                Card Name: <input type="text" name="card_name"><br><br>
                Front Text: <input type="text" name="front_text"><br><br>
                Front Media (X: Image, Y: Video) <input type="text" name="front_media"><br><br>
                Back Text: <input type="text" name="back_text"><br><br>
                Back Media (X: Image, Y: Video) <input type="text" name="back_media"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="CREATE CARD" onClick="createCard(this.form)">
            </form>
        </div>

       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          function createCard(input_form) {
             alert("Card is being created!");
              $.ajax({
                  url: "create_card.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: $(input_form).serialize()
              });
          }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```